# Running AsyncHttpClient with JUNIT Tests

Tags: java, android

I've got the following JUnit test I've been trying to run. When I try to print out the userHash string, I get that the string is null. This suggests that the httpclient isn't running at all. I've been following this post...

https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/173

Here is my class.

```
public class ECApiManagerTests {
    InstrumentationTestCase runnerHelper = new InstrumentationTestCase();
    private final String userEmail = "removed";
    private final String passWord = "removed";
    String userHash;


    @Test
    public void testPOST()throws Throwable{
        final AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();


        runnerHelper.runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                params.put("email", userEmail);
                params.put("password", passWord);
                httpClient.post("https://edu.chat/api/login/", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        //called when response code 200
                        userHash = new String(responseBody);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                    }
                });


            }
        });

        try {
            System.out.println(userHash);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(userHash);
            Assert.assertEquals("true", obj.getString("success"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forgot the `CountdownLatch` part of the solution.  It is important because the request is asynchronous, so you need to wait until the request finishes before looking at the results.  The latch does this by having the calling thread wait until `onFinish` is called from the response handler.

```
public class ECApiManagerTests {
    InstrumentationTestCase runnerHelper = new InstrumentationTestCase();
    private final String userEmail = "removed";
    private final String passWord = "removed";
    String userHash;

    @Test
    public void testPOST()throws Throwable{
        final AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
        final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

        runnerHelper.runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                params.put("email", userEmail);
                params.put("password", passWord);
                httpClient.post("https://edu.chat/api/login/", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        //called when response code 200
                        userHash = new String(responseBody);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        signal.countDown();
                    }
                });


            }
        });
        try {
            signal.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // wait for callback
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(userHash);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(userHash);
            Assert.assertEquals("true", obj.getString("success"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Did you add logging to see if your `onFailure` is being called.  If so, `userHash` will be `null`

Comment: Yes. It seems like its never being called.. Do you have any idea why that is?